# Computer keeps deleting mbrs on all drives

Tags: hard-drive, boot, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I'm having problems with a computer that, for some weird reason is breaking the boot on my HDDs, I tried using another HDD I had to install windows and fix the other hard drives, but after install, it can't boot too, windows boot files get damaged after installation, and I can't boot.

I had recovered all files and got the hard drives running again with testdisk before, but then, after some weeks the computer shut itself off suddenly and then couldn't boot again, and the other hard drives I have can't boot too.

I'm trying to install puppy linux on a usb stick, but it doesn't boot too, the only thing I managed to boot in that machine was an usb stick with the windows 8.1 installer.

Comment: I managed to make a SystemRescueCD bootable usb and fixed it with testdisk, that recovered the Master File Table and recovered all the files.  
Some days later, I had the same problem after shuting it down, fixed the HDD but had to reinstall windows, and it moved my files to windows.old.  
After some weeks, the same problem, I fixed the MFT, but now windows installer says it can't boot from that disk, in any partition in that disk, and nothing I did seems to make it bootable again.
The computer is old, the HDD is old 250 Gb, but has lots of important files, and the HDD seems to be failing..

Answer (score 0):

Quite a complex situation, without any required details ... How about some malware teasing?

So, please, some details: which type of machine, OS's, boot types/sectors, boot media formatting, etc. in question ...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/569639)

Comment: OK ... but, anyway, it's too risky to give any answer/hint to this critical type of question without knowing even some basic details on it, so, will so far not risk myself answering.